# Find request from Mobile app or web browser

Tags: java, android, http, ionic-framework

I want find all the request coming from the mobile app to server and from any browser to the server. Let us suppose that I have an endpoint to show products '/showProducts'. Now I want to store all the request coming from the mobile app and then perform some additional operations on them.

How to find that the API is hit from the mobile app or from the web browser in JAVA?

OR the question can be thought as:

I want my API to run only through mobile apps. How do I know that the request has come from the mobile app?

Comment: You should check the HTTP header, more specific the User-Agent string.

Comment: Can you make changes on the mobile app or browser app? You could add a custom header to your requests for server to know its origin